# How do I modify the shaded parts of the PBR?

Tags: shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, cesiumjs

**Hello everyone!**

**I added 3dtiles data in Cesium, I want it to render more realistic, so I added a pbr function to it**

**At some angles, the model looks bright:**

[image]

**But the shaded part looks strange,my texture on the model was replaced with a color**


I've tried to **clamp()** to fix the results, but it just makes the model look white,

**How can I display the model's texture in the shaded part?**

[image]

This is my shader code:

```
   vec3 lambertianDiffuse(vec3 diffuseColor)
    {
        return diffuseColor / czm_pi;
    }
    
    vec3 fresnelSchlick2(vec3 f0, vec3 f90, float VdotH)
    {
        return f0 + (f90 - f0) * pow(clamp(1.0 - VdotH, 0.0, 1.0), 5.0);
    }
    
    float smithVisibilityG1(float NdotV, float roughness)
    {
        // this is the k value for direct lighting.
        // for image based lighting it will be roughness^2 / 2
        float k = (roughness + 1.0) * (roughness + 1.0) / 8.0;
        return NdotV / (NdotV * (1.0 - k) + k);
    }
    
    float smithVisibilityGGX(float roughness, float NdotL, float NdotV)
    {
        return (
            smithVisibilityG1(NdotL, roughness) *
            smithVisibilityG1(NdotV, roughness)
        );
    }
    
    float GGX(float roughness, float NdotH)
    {
        float roughnessSquared = roughness * roughness;
        float f = (NdotH * roughnessSquared - NdotH) * NdotH + 1.0;
        return roughnessSquared / (czm_pi * f * f);
    }
    
    /**
     * @name czm_pbrlighting
     * @glslFunction
     * @param {vec3} positionEC The position of the fragment in eye coordinates
     * @param {vec3} normalEC The surface normal in eye coordinates
     * @param {vec3} lightDirectionEC Unit vector pointing to the light source in eye coordinates.
     * @param {vec3} lightColorHdr radiance of the light source. This is a HDR value.
     * @param {czm_pbrParameters} The computed PBR parameters.
     * @return {vec3} The computed HDR color
     *
     * @example
     * czm_pbrParameters pbrParameters = czm_pbrMetallicRoughnessMaterial(
     *  baseColor,
     *  metallic,
     *  roughness
     * );
     * vec3 color = czm_pbrlighting(
     *  positionEC,
     *  normalEC,
     *  lightDirectionEC,
     *  lightColorHdr,
     *  pbrParameters);
     */
    vec3 czm_pbrLighting(
        vec3 positionEC,
        vec3 normalEC,
        vec3 lightDirectionEC,
        vec3 lightColorHdr,
        czm_pbrParameters pbrParameters
    )
    {
        vec3 v = -normalize(positionEC);
        vec3 l = normalize(lightDirectionEC);
        vec3 h = normalize(v + l);
        vec3 n = normalEC;
        float NdotL = clamp(dot(n, l), 0.001, 1.0);
        float NdotV = abs(dot(n, v)) + 0.001;
        float NdotH = clamp(dot(n, h), 0.0, 1.0);
        float LdotH = clamp(dot(l, h), 0.0, 1.0);
        float VdotH = clamp(dot(v, h), 0.0, 1.0);
    
        vec3 f0 = pbrParameters.f0;
        float reflectance = max(max(f0.r, f0.g), f0.b);
        vec3 f90 = vec3(clamp(reflectance * 25.0, 0.0, 1.0));
        vec3 F = fresnelSchlick2(f0, f90, VdotH);
    
        float alpha = pbrParameters.roughness;
        float G = smithVisibilityGGX(alpha, NdotL, NdotV);
        float D = GGX(alpha, NdotH);
        vec3 specularContribution = F * G * D / (4.0 * NdotL * NdotV);
    
        vec3 diffuseColor = pbrParameters.diffuseColor;
        // F here represents the specular contribution
        vec3 diffuseContribution = (1.0 - F) * lambertianDiffuse(diffuseColor);
    
        // Lo = (diffuse + specular) * Li * NdotL
        return (diffuseContribution + specularContribution) * NdotL * lightColorHdr;
    }


**Thank you all.**
```

**Add the complete shader code:**

```
vec3 getPhongColor(vec3 positionToEyeEC, vec3 normalEC, vec3 color) {
  czm_material material;
  material.diffuse = color;
  material.specular = 0.0;
  material.shininess = 1.0;
  material.normal = normalEC;
  material.emission = vec3(0.0);
  material.alpha = 1.0;

  return clamp(czm_phong(normalize(positionToEyeEC), material, czm_lightDirectionEC).rgb + 0.2, vec3(0.), vec3(1.));
}

    vec3 computePbrLighting(czm_modelMaterial inputMaterial)
    {
      czm_pbrParameters pbrParameters;
      pbrParameters.diffuseColor = inputMaterial.diffuse;
      pbrParameters.f0 = inputMaterial.specular;
      pbrParameters.roughness = inputMaterial.roughness;

      vec3 lightColorHdr = czm_lightColorHdr;

      vec3 color = inputMaterial.diffuse;
      #ifdef HAS_NORMALS
      color = czm_pbrLighting(
        v_positionEC,
        inputMaterial.normalEC,
        czm_lightDirectionEC,
        lightColorHdr,
        pbrParameters
      );
      #endif



      // color *= inputMaterial.occlusion;
      // color += inputMaterial.emissive;

      color = mix(color, inputMaterial.diffuse, 0.0995);

      // In HDR mode, the frame buffer is in linear color space. The
      // post-processing stages (see PostProcessStageCollection) will handle
      // tonemapping. However, if HDR is not enabled, we must tonemap else large
      // values may be clamped to 1.0
      #ifndef HDR
      color = czm_acesTonemapping(color);
      #endif
      return color * 1.2;
    }
    void fragmentMain(FragmentInput fsInput, inout czm_modelMaterial material) {
      
vec3 positionMC = fsInput.attributes.positionMC;
vec3 normalEC = fsInput.attributes.normalEC;
vec3 positionToEyeEC = -fsInput.attributes.positionEC;
vec2 st = fsInput.attributes.texCoord_0;
float width = floor(fsInput.attributes.buildinglength + 0.5);
float height = floor(fsInput.attributes.buildingheight + 0.5);
float buildingType = floor(fsInput.attributes.buildingtype + .5);

bool isTop = dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), v_normalMC) > 0.999;
bool isBottom = dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0), v_normalMC) > 0.999;
vec3 color = material.diffuse;
bool isOutHeatZone = color == vec3(0.);
bool isHighlight = color == vec3(0., 0., 1.);
st = vec2(1. - st.x, 1. - st.y);


      if(isHighlight) {
        
if (isTop) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(.82, .8, .22);
} else {
  material.diffuse = getPhongColor(positionToEyeEC, normalEC, vec3(.87, .82, .04));
}

      } else if(isOutHeatZone) {
        const float size = 9.;
        float s = size;

        for(int i = int(size); i > 3; i--) {
          if(mod(height, float(i)) == 0.) {
            break;
          } else {
            s--;
          }
        }
        float textureX = mod(st.x * width, s) / s;
        float textureY = mod(st.y * height, s) / s;

        if (isTop) {
          if (buildingType == 1060102.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.3137254901960784, 0.3607843137254902, 0.3686274509803922);
}else if (buildingType == 1060103.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else if (buildingType == 1060201.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else if (buildingType == 1060202.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else if (buildingType == 1060203.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else if (buildingType == 1060204.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else if (buildingType == 1060101.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else if (buildingType == 1060501.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else if (buildingType == 1060502.) {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608, 0.6431372549019608);
}else {
  material.diffuse = vec3(0.8509803921568627, 0.8509803921568627, 0.8509803921568627);
}
        } else {
          if (buildingType == 1060102.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 0.) / 3., (textureY + 1.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060103.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 1.) / 3., (textureY + 1.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060201.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 0.) / 3., (textureY + 0.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060202.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 0.) / 3., (textureY + 0.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060203.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 0.) / 3., (textureY + 0.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060204.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 0.) / 3., (textureY + 0.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060101.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 1.) / 3., (textureY + 0.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060501.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 2.) / 3., (textureY + 1.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else if (buildingType == 1060502.) {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 2.) / 3., (textureY + 1.) / 2.)).rgb;
} else {
  material.diffuse = texture2D(u_texture, vec2((textureX + 2.) / 3., (textureY + 0.) / 2.)).rgb;
} 
        }
        material.diffuse = computePbrLighting(material);
      } else {
        
if (!isTop) {
  float deep = clamp(st.y + .5, .5, 1.) * 1.5;
  vec3 phongColor = getPhongColor(positionToEyeEC, normalEC, color * deep);
  material.diffuse = mix(phongColor, color * .7, .3);
}

      }
    }"
```

Comment: Where exactly do you look up the texture in your shader? I can't find that part in the code.

Comment: You probably need exposure and tonemapping in there too.

Comment: I added the shader code